# Gauge connection on topological 3-manifold

Tags: differential-geometry, gauge-theory, topological-field-theory

To describe a gauge theory on a topological nontrivial 3-manifold we need to consider a good cover of the manifold in contractible open sets with associated set of 3-connections:

$A=\{v_a,\lambda_{ab},n_{abc}\}$

where $v_a$ is related to the set $U_a$, $\lambda_{ab}$ to the intersection of two sets $U_a$ and $U_b$ and $n_{abc}$ to the intersection of three sets. The variables associated to intersections are related to the change of 1-forms  $v_a$ defined in every set:

$(\delta v)_{ab}:=v_b-v_a=d\lambda_{ab}$

$(\delta \lambda)_{abc}:=\lambda_{ab}-\lambda_{ac}+\lambda_{bc}=n_{abc}$

$(\delta n)_{abc}=0$

However, if the manifold has trivial homology we can globally define a 1-form as connection over the whole manifold.

1. How to demonstrate the last statement according to relations above? Is there some way to say that $d \lambda_{ab}=0$ if the first homology group is trivial?
2. The description above could be made also in the language of fiber bundles. Indeed, if the manifold is globally trivializable it admits a global section, so we can define a 1-form connection over the whole manifold. How to demostrate that if se the manifold has trivial homology then it is globally trivializable?

Comment: Your second question is wholly different than the first and independent from the answer to the first question. Moreover it is purely a mathematical question. Consider asking it separately on [mathSE](https://math.stackexchange.com/).